# Trying to send pagination information in response object but only passing through data property c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I have been attempting to send pagination information to the front end from a c# backend. I have found this tutorial that I have followed directly: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/pagination-in-aspnet-core-webapi/

I am using ASP.NET from my understanding and the class I'm working with extends ControllerBase.

I am able to get my backend setup and create the Response and PagedResponse wrapper classes that have been introduced. I don't go further as I don't have a need for the additional features the guide provides.

Just to clarify what I'd like, a response object looks like this when I sent it to the frontend:

[Snippet of Response Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaJiX.png)

```
RESPONSE OBJECT
{
  config
  data
  headers
  request
  status
  statusText
}
```

Usually inside of the data property of this object you would see the actual data that the front end is interested. By following the tutorial I was expecting to learn how to add a property to the response object "pageCount", and result in something like this:

```
RESPONSE OBJECT
{
  config
  data
  headers
  request
  status
  statusText
  pageCount
}
```

However, the actual result has the same response object, but with a different data property. Inside of the data property, this is what it looks like:

```
DATA PROPERTY
{
  data
  errors
  message
  pageCount
  succeeded
}
```

I don't like this approach as the data property of the response object has additional information inside of it that's not the data. I'd instead like to be able to add the page count to response. Ideally the front end would be able to get pages from assigning a variable like 'response' to the response object and doing something like response.pageCount to determine the available pages as well as response.data to get the actual data.

I have been searching for a way to add the information to the response object and haven't found any luck. I did find a solution talking about adding it to headers but that's not where I want to add it. Additionally, I did find some outdated code that no longer works on my version.

Ideally, once I find a solution to send the pageCount back, the whole response and data structure will look like this:

```
RESPONSE OBJECT
{
  config
  data:
    [Array of Items] (No additional information inside of data)
  headers
  request
  status
  statusText
  pageCount
}
```

Please let me know if any additional information is needed. Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

EDIT Additional Code & Information:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult GetAll([FromHeader(Name = "itemsPerPage")] int? itemsPerPage, [FromHeader(Name = "sortBy")] string? sortBy, [FromHeader(Name = "page")] int? page) {
    List<Things> things = repo.GetAll(itemsPerPage, sortBy, page);
    return new JsonResult(new PagedResponse<List<Things>>(things, things.Count));

}
```

If you were to console.log() a regular response from the backend on the front end without any pagination information, the response object would look like this

[Snippet of Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yozxw.png)

This is what I'm calling the "Response" Object.

As you can see there is a data property on this Response Object:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6ugQ.png)

And as you can see from the picture, it is an array of items. There is no additional information inside of the data property. An example of something extra would be pagination information like "PageCount". I do not want the "Page Count" property inside of the data property. However, when following the guide I linked above, that is the result I get.

Here is what I would like my response object to look like:

[Snippet of Ideal Response Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zCtv.png)

As you can see the PageCount property is a property of the Response Object, and not inside of the data property.

Now this is what my response object looks like after I what I've attempted through the tutorial:

[Snippet of Response after finishing tutorail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtCyK.png)

As you can see inside of the data property, there is another data property. You can see that the pagesCount is inside of the top level data property. And the additional attributes such as errors and message are additional properties that the tutorial added.

Hopefully that gives you an idea of what I've done and how the result is not what I would've expected.

So my direct question right now is either How can I overwrite the Response Object completely so that I can directly control what it looks like including adding a pageCount property. Or Alternatively, how can I add a single property pageCount to the already existing response object?

Comment: can you state your problem?

Comment: What I want to happen is for the response object to have an additional property "pageCount" When I send it to the front end. The problem is that by following this tutorial, the result is that the response object doesn't have pageCount itself, but the data property of the response object has the page count. I don't like this result because I thinkt hat the data property shouldn't have any additional information.

To breifly summarize. I want to add a page count property to the "Response" Object. This being the object that the back end sends to the front end with status codes/headers.

Comment: Can you please include the code you are using in the browser to make the request? The "response object" you describe is not the response, it's a user-defined wrapper around the response (`data`), which wasn't defined in the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: Yea, without posting relevant codes where you think the problem might be I'd have to read the tutorial and follow along to spot the problem. I also noticed `totalRecords` is included in the payload response.

Comment: @beautifulcoder I have updated my post with more information. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Thank you very much for that information. I believe you are right that there is a custom wrapper. I appear to have discovered it was on the front end from a stream-http library. I will look into this further and if I discover the resolution I will update the title and post an answer!

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Williamson was the one who really answered my question. He pointed out that the response Object I was assuming was coming from the backend was actually not the response. And the information inside of the data property was what was actually being returned by the backend.

I've discovered that the reason I'm seeing that wrapper object is actually because I'm using axios through npm to access responses.

Basically the Axios NPM package describes the Response Schema:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema

This shows the response object I was looking at.

The solution that I settled on was using response headers to add the page count there.

To add the response headers, I did this code:

```
public List<Things> GetAll([FromHeader(Name = "itemsPerPage")] int? itemsPerPage, [FromHeader(Name = "sortBy")] string? sortBy, [FromHeader(Name = "page")] int? page) {

    List<Things> things = repo.GetAll(itemsPerPage, sortBy, page);
    Response.Headers.Add("Pages", things.Count.ToString());
    return things;

}
```

And this is how I accessed the pages header on the front end using AXIOS

```
useEffect(() => {
  endPointServiceMethod(query).then((response: any) => {
    console.log('Pages Headers');
    console.log(response.headers['pages']);
    console.log('Data');
    console.log(response.data);
    setItems(response);
  });
}, []);
```

Once again, thank you Andrew Williamson for pointing out the answer!

Comment: For future reference, you can view the raw contents of the request and response in Chrome through the *network* tab, or you can test your api using a tool like PostMan